# Convert columns into category and merge data (panda, dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a big dataframe with individual data on stocks. 
Sample:

```
import pandas as pd 


# initialize list of lists 
data = [["01.01.2019"  , 10, 15, 14 ],["02.01.2019" , 11, 15, 18]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date", 'AAPL', 'MMM', "GS"]) 

# print dataframe. 
df 

###Date AAPL    MMM GS
0   01.01.2019  10  15  14
1   02.01.2019  11  15  18
```

Now I would like to convert this data, accordingly, so I get the following output. 
The data values should be appended, as well as the date variable and the previous columns titles shall appear merged in one column "Name" as strings.

```
# initialize list of lists 
data = [["01.01.2019" , 'AAPL', 10],["02.01.2019" , 'AAPL', 11],  ["01.01.2019", 'MMM', 15], ["02.01.2019", 'MMM', 15],  ["01.01.2019", 'GS', 14], ["02.01.2019", 'GS', 18]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date", 'Name', 'Data']) 

# print dataframe. 
df 


###    Date Name    Data
0   01.01.2019  AAPL    10
1   02.01.2019  AAPL    11
2   01.01.2019  MMM     15
3   02.01.2019  MMM     15
4   01.01.2019  GS      14
5   02.01.2019  GS      18
```

What works for me for this small sample is something I cannot use for the whole dataframe, as it is too big. Also this solution would also just consider two companies.

```
df_new = df[["Date", "AAPL"]].append(df[["Date", "MMM"]])
df_new["Data"] = df_new.max(axis=1)
df_new["Name"] =  "AAPL"
df_new= df_new.reset_index()
df_new.loc[2:3,'Name'] = "MMM"

df_new.drop(df_new.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_new

### Date    Data    Name
0   01.01.2019  10.0    AAPL
1   02.01.2019  11.0    AAPL
2   01.01.2019  15.0    MMM
3   02.01.2019  15.0    MMM
```

I believe there are solutions out there, but I could not find a good one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this would be something like pivot?  I haven't used that before though, so perhaps do some research into that...

Comment: I believe melt is similiar to your suggestion pivot, so I assume it could also be helpful here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `melt` function of `pandas`

```py
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['Date'], value_vars = ['AAPL', 'MMM', 'GS'])
         Date variable  value
0  01.01.2019     AAPL     10
1  02.01.2019     AAPL     11
2  01.01.2019      MMM     15
3  02.01.2019      MMM     15
4  01.01.2019       GS     14
5  02.01.2019       GS     18
```